# How can I see whether an international patent application was filed under the Patent Cooperation Treaty (PCT)?

Tags: patent-applications, international, pct

Given a patent application filed internationally, e.g. https://patents.google.com/patent/GB2571811A/, how can I see whether it was filed under the Patent Cooperation Treaty (PCT)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the link you provide to google patents. Find “global dossier”. You will see there where corresponding applications have been filed.

I saw US but not PCT. A PCT application starts with WO.

Note - it is not really global. If there was a counterpart filed in Taiwan I would not expect it to be visible there.